# Social login authentication via wordpress rest api

Tags: plugins, rest-api, authentication

I am building a Vue app powered by Wordpress Rest API. After stumbling upon many options for authentication, I chose JWT authentication. However, i still haven't been able to find the solution for social login via REST API. Any direction would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How is your site issuing JWTs? I'd guess you'd just have to extend that mechanism to handle oAuth login / signup, and that might be simplest to do that using an existing separate-page solution that then redirects back to your Vue app once the JWT is ready.

Comment: @Rup I am using a plugin JWT Authentication for WP-API - 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/